# PHP regex for finding token in ugly string

Tags: php, regex, regex-greedy

Suppose I have this ugly string:

```
$uglyString = 'thing.header.setLoadBaseData(true);</script><script type=\'text/javascript\'>window.preload={"serverVersion":"20161019","locale":"en_US","token":{"value":"aAdcDqpeWcaJzmmWeH9ElQ:1477340771943","valid":43200000},"accounts":[{"id":"55153549","datasetId":"a55153549w0p0","s4id":"FU\/llMk3qzAP6ClSIHqMU73huAo=","name":"Ga abd Gub","isPremium":false,"starred":false,"totalNumberOfProfiles":1,"wprops":[{"id":"88276407","datasetId":"a55153549w88276407p0","s4id":"T1xfVTHwcwLUwkUSlzEfZrRYL3E=","name":"GrubHub Preview","number":1,"configuredForAppData":false,"configuredForWebData":true,"isPr';
```

From the above string, I need to extract the value `aAdcDqpeWcaJzmmWeH9ElQ:1477340771943` using PHP.

It is found next to `token`. The token will always appear like `"token":{"value":"aAdcDqpeWcaJzmmWeH9ElQ:1477340771943"`

This is what I have but it is not working

```
preg_match('/(?<=token":{"value":)(.*)(?=.*)/', $uglyString, $matches);
```

Comment: `/"token":\{"value":"([^"]+)"/`

Comment: This is the solution

Comment: Link: https://regex101.com/r/N4m0u1/1

Comment: You really should use JSON object to obtain `token.value`. The ugly string could get agiler (as per Murphy's law) and the Regex solution would be unpredictable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use what is constant and capture what will change:

```
preg_match('/"token":{"value":"([^"]+)"/', $uglyString, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

So match all of the constant stuff up until the `"`, then capture everything that is not a `"` up until the final `"`.

Comment: That's a good approach to this. I need to get better at regex